# Change Datetime format in Microsoft Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, format

Hi i want to change the default datetime type in sql server. I have already table who has rows and i dont want to delete them. Now the datetime format that had rows is: `2015-11-16 09:04:06.000` and i want to change in `16.11.2015 09:04:06` and every new row that i insert i want to take this datetime format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not store `DATETIME` values in the way you're thinking it does.  The value that you see is simply what the DBMS is choosing to render the data as.  If you wish to change the display of the `DATETIME` type, you can use the `FORMAT()` built-in function in `SQL Server 2012` or later versions, but keep in mind this is converting it to a `VARCHAR`

You can get the format you desire via the following:

```
SELECT FORMAT(YourDateField, N'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: i want to write: select datecolumn from table and i want to get result: dd.MM.yyyy 00:00:000 .. I dont want to select with format in my queries. Is the way to do this with function? or can i change the sql server lanquage? or something.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't store a format - if you want to change how it's displayed, you need convert it to a `VARCHAR` with the format you desire.  SQL Server is not the presentation layer.

Comment: is there way to give a query: select datecolumn from table and i take a format that i want and back of all this where i select datecolmn sql server understand that must give me the format that i give it to him. Example if i use some function or change language or i dont know

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  If you want to select something in a specific format, you need to specify that in your query.  The query I provided in my answer would return the format you desire.

Comment: i ve change server and the problem is that the new server has other datetime format and i have allready software that connect to this database and its impossible to change all queries from software. I want to change the datetime format in database. Or if its not possible that i want somehow when i select the column who is datetime get the format that i want. But i dont want to select Convert(..) or something like that. I search and i found that i ve done with this using formula in column properties

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as format of the `DATETIME` data type, it has no format by nature, formatted is the text representation you can set when converting to `VARCHAR` or some visualization settings of the client / IDE.

If you, however, want to be able to insert dates using string representations that are alternatively formatted (i.e. control the way string input is parsed to datetime type) you can check [SET DATEFORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - as explained in the remarks section this will not change the display representation of date fields / variables.

Answer (score 0):

SQL serve provide wide range of date formatting function or way by using that user can change date format as per his requirement.

Some of are giver bellow.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),GETDATE())
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),10)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),6)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),106)
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),113)
```